# DKIM Settings to prevent outgoing mail from server marked as spam

Tags: email, dkim

We have automated email alerts from a web application hosted on a VPS. Google is marking our outgoing emails from server as SPAM. So, none of our users with a GMail account are receiving the emails.

I have done the required settings for SPF & DKIM, but to no avail.
On viewing the header of the emails, I see the following message against DKIM

```
dkim=neutral (invalid public key) header.i=@domain.com
```

I cannot make out what is wrong here. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Double check your dkim public-key in TXT record and compare it with the key from the key generation program.
This error means that your public and private keys are not suitable.